# How to pause execution while uploading a file to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading files to Firebase Storage, and need to wait till the file is finished uploading, and return the URL path to the files.

My current code calls the 'uploadImage' and needs a URL string returned. However the code returns before the file is fully uploaded, then once the file is uploaded, the 'storageReference.downloadURL' executes and sets the imageURL. So the code is working, I need it to pause while uploading the files, then return the URL. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
//
//  FirebaseStorage.swift
//  ItemizePro
//
//  Created by Tyler Wasick on 6/14/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tyler Wasick. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class FirebaseStorageService {

    // Upload image to Firebase Storage
    static func uploadImage(image:UIImage, fileType:String) -> String {

        // Image URL (String)
        var imageURL = ""

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

            // Get UID
            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

            // Setup variables
            let fileName = UUID().uuidString

            // Create a Firebase Storage reference
            let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(fileType)/\(uid!)/\(fileName).jpg")

            // Uploads the image to Firebase Storage
            let photoData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)

            guard photoData != nil else {
                print("No photo provided")
                return "NoPhoto"
            }

            storageReference.putData(photoData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in

                // Check for upload errors
                if err != nil {

                    // If an error has occured, print the error (to console) and return
                    print(err!)
                    return
                }
                else {
                    // Set image URL
                    storageReference.downloadURL { (url, err) in

                        // Check for errors
                        if err != nil {

                            // If an error has occured, print the error (to console) and return
                            print(err!)
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            print("Upload successful!")
                            imageURL = url!.absoluteString
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Returns a string of the url location
            return imageURL
        }

        return imageURL
    }
}
```

Comment: `storageReference.putData()` is asynchronous and returns immediately before the upload is finished.  The callback will tell you when it's done.

Comment: Is there a method that is not asynchronous?

Comment: No, all Firebase APIs are asynchronous.  https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93